# bower install on Visual Studio Online build

Tags: bower, build-process, azure-devops

Using the 'new' build system, I want to create a bower install step.
I tried command prompt using:

```
tool: node_modules/.bin/bower.cmd
arguments: install
```

but that return this error :

```
node_modules/.bin/bower.cmd install
Error message highlight pattern: 
Warning message highlight pattern: 
##[error]File not found: node_modules/.bin/bower.cmd
```

I have bower on my npm dependencies and npminstall step before my bower-install command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you run the `npm install bower` before trying to run the command to install the packages from bower?

Comment: I see that Bower is installed by default of the build servers hosted by Microsoft. It means, if you are using Microsoft hosted server, you can just run the command `bower install` without having to specify a path

Comment: that was my first thought but doing it gives me an error. I will do it again and update with the specific error on that command.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're using the Microsoft hosted build server?

Comment: yes, microsoft hosted build server. trying with powershell instead of command prompt now: same  The term 'C:\a\cc6b5771\ProjectName\bower' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.

Comment: Can you try to use this path to run bower: `C:\NPM\Modules\bower.cmd` it is where bower is installed the build server

Comment: yes! that worked! thank you. How did you know where bower was located?

Comment: If you go to `https://xxx.visualstudio.com/_admin` then click on "Agent pools", then select the Hosted pool. You should see the Microsoft build server and look at the path on the right

Comment: @Fabien I noticed, bower is listed for "Hosted" Agent pools, but not for "Hosted VS2017". This seems a bit weird on Microsoft's part, especially because bower is integrated into VS2017, so I would expect the agents to support this too. I also verified if "dotnet build" or "dotnet restore" automatically restore the packages in VSTS builds, and they don't.

Comment: It turns out bower is installed at the same location (C:\NPM\Modules\bower.cmd) in Hosted VS2017 queue as well, even though it's not listed in "User capabilities" in the agent pool page. Also, this bower extension is useful: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=touchify.vsts-bower